# Json schema pattern to exclude numbers and special characters in string

Tags: regex, json-schema-validator

I ma working on a JSON schema pattern to exclude numbers and special characters in string, and here is what I have now:

```
"properties": {
  "applicationName": {
    "description": "TPG Application Name",
    "type": "string",
    "pattern": "[^0-9!@#$%^&*()_+\\-=\\[\\]{};':\"\\\\|,.<>\\/?\\s\\n]"
},
```

This is not working as intended, e.g. it does not allow whitespace.

**Input JSON:**

```
{
   "applicationName": "TestName",    
}
```

Comment: and if i want space also?

Comment: Where's the question?

Comment: its working thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Judging by the `"[^0-9!@#$%^&*()_+\\-=\\[\\]{};':\"\\\\|,.<>\\/?\\s\\n]"` pattern, you want to match any char but digits, whitespace and special characters (punctuation and symbols). Here, whitespace cannot be matched because `\s` is present inside the negated character class, and the pattern is matching partially, i.e. it will validate any string that contains a char other than the characters listed in the set. `?a!` will match since there is `a`, e.g.

The simplest solution is to match letters and whitespace, from start till end of string:

```
"^[A-Za-z\\s]*$"
```

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `[A-Za-z\\s]*` - 0+ letters or whitespace
- `$` - end of string.